# Linux - how change chmod of /

Tags: linux, root, chmod

How can I change chmod of /?

When I run

```
chmod 755 /
```

under root, I get

```
Operation not permitted
```

**Why I need it?**

I am installing (logged as root) `apt-get install memcached` and I get error:

```
failed to move /initrd.img:Permission denied at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic.postinst line 495.
```

Comment: if you do this, linux won't boot anymore. The permissions on / are not random/arbitrary.

Comment: @H2CO3: they are 755 by default. Probable he wants to change permissions back.

Comment: Can you tell us how  your try to run `apt-get`? Are you using `sudo` or ..?

Comment: @TomTichý This is very odd .. I assume this is the first time you've come across this. What are you trying to install? Have you made any other changes to permissions of system directories? Just trying to get a more complete picture, though it may be impossible to do w/o having hands on the system.

Comment: What are the current permissions on the root directory (`ls -ld /`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that your root filesystem is mounted readonly.
You need to check it, for example, creating a file in `/root`:

```
# touch /root/hello
```

Then you will see if it is really so.

If it mounted readonly, you can try to remount it rewrite and see what happened:

```
# mount -o rw,remount /
```

Ok, how we've known after the discussion there were an immutable bit on the filesystem.

```
# lsattr -d /
----i--------e- /
```

You can remove this bit with `chattr -i /`. Don't forget to set it back after your operations:

```
# chattr -i /
# # something
# chattr +i /
```

Comment: then you need to open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic.postinst` at the line 495 and show us what is the line there.

Comment: `rename("$kimage", "$kimage.$$") || die "failed to move " . $image_dest . "$kimage:$!";`

Comment: can you try to rename `/initrd.img`? `mv /initrd.img /initrd.img.save` dont't forget to rename it back!

Comment: no, I can't `mv: cannot move '/initrd.img' to '/initrd.img.save': Permission denied`

Comment: and copy also? `cp /initrd.img /initrd.img.save` ?

Comment: Touching to `/root/hello` was fine. I can't touch to `/initrd.img.save` (Permission denied again).

Comment: can you please check attributes of `/`? `lsattr -d /` ?

Comment: Not at all! That was super :) exciting chase :) don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: +1 for persistence and good detective/diagnostic work! (as promised)

Answer (score 4):

Do you have root privileges? Mere mortals (i.e., regular users :-) are not permitted to make these changes

Comment: Never mind mere mortals, I can't fathom any reason why anyone (even root users) would want to change the privilege of root and literally nothing else.

Comment: @Palladium agreed .. no argument here

Comment: Yes, I have root privileges. I want to change it, because apt-get wants write to / and it falls.

Comment: @TomTichý: that is a bad idea. show us better what writes `apt-get`

Comment: @TomTichý What IgorChubin said, this would be more a problem with the `apt-get` than making changes to the root directory

Comment: @TomTichý Rather than chmodding root, you should just run `sudo apt-get` instead.

Comment: I am logged under root - whye `sudo apt-get`?

Comment: @TomTichý Never mind. I thought you were trying to `apt-get` from non-root, failed, then went into root to `chmod` the root directory. But nevertheless, you really should be doing everything - including `sudo apt-get` - from a non-root account with full sudo power. Dealing with root is just bad practice.

Comment: I added another suggestion: the root file system may be mounted readonly. Please check it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use sudo which gives you super user privileges, as others will mention however this kind of stuff is like witchcraft and if it goes horribly wrong then chances are your system will be "unstable" to say the least.

Comment: I am logged under root, so I have super user privileges, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Apt-get doesn't need to change permissions for / or first degree children. Which command do you

Answer (score 0):

use yum tools for installing it automatically clear all the permission and other installing problems . use this command
1. Login as root
2. change permissions of   \ 
   *chmod 777 * 

3.install bmemcached 

** yum install bmemcached**